# i switch from Sublime to phpStorm, why my main folder and subfolder combine in project files tree?

Tags: laravel-5, phpstorm

How can i make customer folder to a subfolder again and create a new folder under the main folder. 
In phpStorm the main Folder and the subfolder was combined like(production/customer) in my Project files. Please help. this is really wasting my time.

Comment: How about posting a screenshot so it does not wasting our time guessing what you have got there?

Comment: i can't this my first post.

Comment: You can upload it to your Dropbox/GoogleDrive/SkyDrive/any image sharing website and just post a link to it here.

Comment: Do you mean your project had two folders or that the two folders were two different projects? Or something different? Could you clarify a bit? :)

Comment: Check this picture. my problem is the production and customer folder are combine in project tree in phpStorm. even though the customer folder is really a subfolder of production.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6P6KhExTEsLXRsZmxDNFlEUWc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using "Project" scope in Project View panel and not any other.

[image]

Any other scope will "combine" empty parent folder with child one.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I'm really having trouble in phpStorm. I think i should study phpStorm first before switching on to it.

Comment: @fibisco 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/ 3) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials